# No QEvent for ApplicationDeactivate nor ApplicationStateChange

Tags: macos, qt, events

I would like to be notified when the user switch to another application so I use the *installEventFilter* method to catch the events:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->installEventFilter(this);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *sender, QEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << event->type();
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(sender, event);
}
```

When I switch to another application I get the following events:

- *WindowDeactivate*
- *ActivationChange*
- *UpdateRequest*
- *Paint*

Shouldn't I receive *ApplicationDeactivate* (which seems to be deprecated) or *ApplicationStateChange* when I switch to another application?

I'm under *MacOS* and test with the following *Qt* versions: *5.1.1*, *5.2.0*, *5.2.1*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should connect to the `QGuiApplication::applicationStateChanged` signal. If it doesn't fire, that's a bug and should be reported. I don't think you do that, though.

The `ApplicationStateChange` event is used internally by Qt, you're not supposed to worry about it. It is likely sent to the application instance. Also, all of this is for Qt 5.2.x. For 5.1 and earlier, things are different.